# Drive TRIAC with photo TRIAC

Tags: circuit-analysis, triac

Can anyone tell me in the attached circuit why use always-on optotriac to drive TRIAC?

What is the purpose of using phototriac in the circuit?

This circuit is used to control the speed of ac motor and between pin 1 and 2 of CN2 is placed the RV1 (potentiometer).

Usually use phototriac for isolation but in this circuit, we don't need isolation. There is not a DC source or microcontroller for turning on the optotriac.

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain where you found the circuit and what it's supposed to do. What is the function of the CN1 terminals?

Comment: Thanks.Please check again.

Answer (score 1):

> *What is the purpose of using phototriac in the circuit?*

- The optical triac will always remain on (once driven from the control input) until the end of the prevailing half AC cycle (as delivered to it via L1/C5 etc.).
- At that point it'll turn-off and remove gate drive to the main triac and...
- The main triac will also turn-off on the same (or subsequent) zero-crossing of anode current.

This is something that is usually wanted to both minimize switching noise and electrical stress on components. It also prevents control pulses that are too small for the main triac having a spurious effect - the opto triac will usually be more sensitive to irrationally thin control pulses and will naturally "latch" thus, normal operation can be more guaranteed.

If the control pulse fires for a little longer than 1 half AC cycle, the main triac will still conduct through the first zero-cross of current and nicely come to rest at the end of the next zero-cross.